# How to use Custom mapper with IObjectMapper on the service

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

Work on aspnetboilerplate asp.net core project, face difficulties on custom mapping. Want to create custom map and want to use it several times as like AUTOMAP profiler.Follow [documentation](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Object-To-Object-Mapping#custom-mapping) but failed to implement this on my project.
My steps are

**1)Create a class MyModule under the XXX.Core**

```
 [DependsOn(typeof(AbpAutoMapperModule))]
    public class MyModule : AbpModule
    {
        public override void PreInitialize()
        {
            Configuration.Modules.AbpAutoMapper().Configurators.Add(config =>
            {
                config.CreateMap<CreateUserInput, CreatUserOutput>()
                      .ForMember(u => u.Password, options => options.Ignore())
                      .ForMember(u => u.OutputEmailAddress, options => options.MapFrom(input => input.EmailAddress));
            });
        }
    }



    public class CreateUserInput
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Surname { get; set; }

        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }
    }

    public class CreatUserOutput
    {
        public string OutputName { get; set; }

        public string Surname { get; set; }

        public string OutputEmailAddress { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

**2)Used above configuration on xxx.Application, service as like bellow**

```
try
            {
                CreateUserInput te = new CreateUserInput
                {
                    EmailAddress = "a@yahoo.com",
                    Name = "input",
                    Password = "test",
                    Surname = "sure"
                };

                CreatUserOutput ot = new CreatUserOutput();

                var temp = _objectMapper.Map<CreatUserOutput>(te);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {


            }
```

I don't understand how to use custom mapper with my injected IObjectMapper on the service.

Comment: It's already configured.

Comment: @aaron will you please explain how it works with the custom mapper, please check my two classes CreateUserInput and CreatUserOutput properties both are not the same, so need to configure them manually.

Comment: Didn't you already configured the mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to create separate automapper profile. 
You need to create file exactly in **Application** layer
You can name it for example AutoMapperProfile.cs
with following:

```cs
 public class AutoMapperProfile : AutoMapper.Profile {
     public AutoMapperProfile () {

         CreateMap<CreateUserInput, CreatUserOutput> ()
             .ForMember (u => u.Password, options => options.Ignore ())
             .ForMember (u => u.OutputEmailAddress, options => options.MapFrom (input => input.EmailAddress));

     }
 }
```

to order this code works make sure that you ApplicationModule.cs
contain following code which responsible for loading profiles.

```cs
public override void Initialize () {
    var thisAssembly = typeof (LicenseManagerApplicationModule).GetAssembly ();

    IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention (thisAssembly);

    Configuration.Modules.AbpAutoMapper ().Configurators.Add (
        // Scan the assembly for classes which inherit from AutoMapper.Profile
        cfg => cfg.AddProfiles (thisAssembly)
    );
}
```